# Can I use conditional formatting in google sheets to force cells to merge given a specific value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I am working on formatting a cash log for work (work in a restaurant and right now we record this by hand) the problem because each days entry isn’t uniform as the number of people working changes so it means manual formatting for each entry.  Below is a picture of what the log I have created looks like [image]

What I would like to happen when then word “Total” appears in the people working column I would like the next three cells in that row to merge and center the text ( in the picture the red circled cells is what I am going for. Is this possible or is this something that needs to be done manually?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Yes, it's possible. This site has a lot of questions about using the Google Sheets conditional formatting feature. Look at the Google Sheets Help menu first; the search box might help you to find the feature and the help article that explains the basics. If you need any more help, please take a look at the questions linked in the post-notice. If you still need help, please read the linked help article in the post-notice to learn what you might do next.

Comment: @Rubén-VolunteerModerator-  OP is asking for a way to dynamically merge cells.

Comment: @Blindspots Noup, the OP is asking about using conditional formatting. However, it might be argued that this is a Problem X-Y. In any case, the OP should start by getting familiar with the Google Sheets basic lingo and the workings of this site. This is solely my humble opinion. If you think you have a better understanding, please feel free to reopen the question.

Comment: @Rubén-VolunteerModerator-what You are correct, what I meant to say is that OP is asking how to use conditional formatting to merge cells.